# Regras do upload no CI não sobrescrevem

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou fazendo um formulário que possui 2 tipos de uploads: um para imagem e um para arquivo. Acontece que as extensões de ambos são diferentes, porém na hora de setar as regras do upload do arquivo o mesmo não sobrescreve as regras anteriores (da imagem) e acaba não aceitando o upload. Essas são as duas funções:

// Função para upar a imagem:

```
   $configImagem['upload_path']   = './files/noticias/imagens';
    $configImagem['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $configImagem['file_name']     = 'Img_noticia_'.date('y-m-d_h-i-s');
    $this->load->library('upload',$configImagem);

    $check = $this->upload->do_upload('imagem');

    if($check == TRUE){ 
        return TRUE;
    } else if($check == FALSE){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('erro', '<strong>Erro:</strong>'.$this->upload->display_errors());
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

// Função para upar o arquivo:

```
    $configArq['upload_path']   = './files/noticias/arquivos';
    $configImagem['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|txt|doc';
    $configArq['file_name']     = 'Arq_noticia_'.date('y-m-d_h-i-s');
    $this->load->library('upload',$configArq);
    $this->upload->initialize($configArq);

    $checkArq = $this->upload->do_upload('arquivo');

    if($checkArq == TRUE){ // caso não ocorra nenhum tipo de erro, o UPLOAD da imagem é feito.
        return TRUE;
    } else if($checkArq == FALSE){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('erro', '<strong>Erro:</strong>'.$this->upload->display_errors());
        return FALSE;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que eu tinha colocado a variável do 'allowed_types' da função 'upArquivo' com o nome errado. Era pra ser $configArq.